# Accessing category codes for Index objects in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series, categorical-data

How can I access the category codes of a Pandas `CategoricalIndex`?

[`pd.Series.cat.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html) is what I use for a series, but this method is not available for `Index` objects. Currently, I convert to a series first, but this is expensive and seems anti-pattern.

This is a minimal example:

```
values = list('abeadc')

s = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(values, categories=list('abcde')))

print(s.cat.codes.tolist())
# [0, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2]

i = pd.CategoricalIndex(pd.Categorical(values, categories=list('abcde')))

print(i.cat.codes.tolist())
# AttributeError: 'CategoricalIndex' object has no attribute 'cat'

print(i.to_series().cat.codes.tolist())
# [0, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the `codes` attribute directly from a `CategoricalIndex`:

```
i.codes
# array([0, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2], dtype=int8)
```

And, as in your example, you can convert this to a Python list:

```
i.codes.tolist()
# [0, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2]
```